# I am trying to execute a code at a specific time using "timer" function from vb.net and combobox to select hours and minutes

Tags: winforms

i am trying to create an application  that has 2 comboboxes , or text , or anny kind of time pick-ing interface,   select the FROM: time   to   TO: time  and the timer to start , and when the difference between the hours is elapsed the timer stops! can u please help me ?

Basicly i am selecting from :hour(min:sec)  , to: hour (min:sec) and then set the timer interval = to the deference from hour in combo box 1  and hour from the combo box , text , etc 2 !
thank you
i am using visual studio  .vb.net

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow. Unfortunately, this is not the kind of question that is suitable here. Questions at SO should be about problems you run into *while programming*. You should be able to show code and point out where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have this logic :

Populate two textboxes (a & b) with this format hh:mm:ss

Convert (a & b) to datetime into two variables

Calculate the delta in millisecs

Program timer interval with the delta time

The timer will launch at desired time.